# Keypress or keydown event handling in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

How to handle those events in grid?

Obvious solutions like

```
grid.on('keypress', handler);
```

or

```
listeners: { keypress: handler }
```

don't work - handler is not being triggered.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

```
grid.view.addElListener('keypress', function() {
    ...
});
```

PS: also formed it as a separated grid plugin: https://gist.github.com/2572486

Comment: @Duleep: what if you try first before you ask?

Comment: `this.getView().addListener('keypress', function() { alert('key'); });` when i Click enter and Tab key not alert came

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [itemkeydown](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-event-itemkeydown) event of Ext.grid.View.